# Get document counts based on unique field values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose job model, each job has a US State. I'm attempting to make 1 query that will give me back the number of jobs that are in each state. Goal would be to populate a US heat map of jobs.

My model looks like the following:

```
const JobSchema = new Schema({
  state: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Available', 'Accepted', 'Closed'],
    default: 'Available'
  }
}, { versionKey: false, timestamps: true });
```

The result I'm looking for would give me something close to:

```
{
  docs: [
    {
      state: 'FL',
      count: 27
    },
    {
      state: 'NC',
      count: 41
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tinkered with iterations if $distinct and others but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should need an aggregation framework query with `$group` stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an aggregation like below:

```
[
  {
     $group: {
        _id: "$state",
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
     }   
  }
]
```

This aggregation groups data by state and the count uses the **$sum** operator and for each document adds one.

Answer (score 0):

Armin's answer above lead down the right path to solving the problem. Kudos to Mongo Atlas for including aggregation in their interface which helped me understand `stages` in aggregation.

There was one additional complexity to my above question that's worth noting here for the next person learning aggregation. The system I'm building is multi-tenant, so jobs belong to one organization - and there are many orgs with many jobs each. I wanted my query to enable getting counts for jobs belonging to a single org.

My aggregation query ended up being:

```
   const aggConfig = [
      {
        $match: {
          organizationId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orgId)
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          '_id': '$state', 
          'count': {
            '$sum': 1
          }
        }
      }
    ];
```

Note that the agg query is an array. Each item in the array is a `stage`, a stage being a `step` in the process - order matters in this case. Step 1 (aggConfig[0]) isolates the result set to only the jobs that belong to a specific organization. Stage 2 (aggConfig[1]) performs the summation of jobs by state, returning the desired array of data.

To execute with a Mongoose model:

```
const agggregatedByState = await JobModel.aggregate(aggConfig);
```